# Django admin panel image upload optimization

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, python-imaging-library

I want to optimize the image uploaded by user from the admin site and store original as well as optimized image and for that

```
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    if obj.image:
        filename = obj.image.name.split('.')[:-1]
        obj.save()
        img = Image.open(obj.image)
        print "Before Size: ", img.size
        w, h = img.size
        size = min(800.0 / w, 800.0 / h)
        w, h = int(w * size), int(h * size)
        print "After Size:", w, h
        img = img.resize((w, h), Image.BICUBIC)
        path = obj.image.path.split('\\')[:-1]
        new_path = "\\".join(path) + "\\{}.jpeg".format("".join(filename))
        img.save('{}'.format(new_path))
        obj.image = img
        obj.save()
```

## Got Error

```
 AttributeError: _committed
```

Any helpful suggestion will be appreciated !

Comment: obj.imgae = img is that a spelling error or error while posting it?

Comment: @Exprator spelling error

Comment: does it print the after size in the console?? and can you say which line is giving the error